# What other HTTP methods besides POST, PUT, DELETE, GET

Tags: asp.net, web-services, rest, asp.net-web-api

I'm creating a web service using ASP.NET's WebAPI.

It seems that the method name in the ApiController is mapped to the Uri.

E.g., PutProducts to add products

What if I want a method that executes say.. a batch file.. like ExecuteProcess1();

This need not return any value of any business worth. It's just for the clients to fire at will, where will this fit in my web service? What should the method be called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the method is modifying some state on your server (such as updating records in a database, writing to files, ...) you should use the POST HTTP verb. Depending on the *resource* that this method is modifying you could have a corresponding API controller:

```
public class SomeResourceController: Controller
{
    public void Post()
    {
        ... do the processing here
    }
}
```

Obviously you will replace *SomeResource* in the name of this controller with the resource you are manipulating (Products, Orders, People, ...).

Comment: So it won't be part of the ApiController?

Comment: Of course that it will be part of an `ApiController`. All actions need to be part of some controller. You just need to pick up the proper name for your resource. It will depend on the kind of information you are manipulating on your server.

Comment: that is not technically true. PUT and DELETE also modify some state on the server.

Comment: @Aliostad, yes that's true. By modifying I meant UPDATE. Of course that if you are going to DELETE you should use the DELETE verb and if you are going to INSERT you should use the PUT verb. I thought that was obvious.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov again not true. INSERT -> POST and UPDATE -> PUT.

Comment: Actually I think that we shouldn't be doing any analogy between the HTTP verb and the SQL statement: http://www.elharo.com/blog/software-development/web-development/2005/12/08/post-vs-put/

Comment: Quote: `PUT is idempotent, which is a fancy way of saying that doing it twice is the same as doing it once.`. So if you say that PUT is INSERT that's not actually true. Because if you attempt to INSERT twice the exact same record, the second might fail due to constraint violations. So it would really be best if we were not assimilating HTTP verbs with SQL. I think we are both wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Simply you can use any HTTP verb you want to make it work. But following the best practice how the REST Api uses, the simple concept is:

1. GET: pull the resource from REST service without changing state of server.
2. POST: create new resource.
3. PUT: Update resource.
4. DELETE: delete resource.

Therefore:

1. If your method: `ExecuteProcess` to run process which creates something on the server, use POST.
2. If it updates something on the server, use PUT.
3. If it deletes something on the server, use DELETE.

Answer (score 0):

You can use POST or GET, it depends on what you are trying to update. But in this case, you should use normal mvc controller and action. WebApi or not, they're still HTTP requests anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you are considering Process as resource then Ideally you will do a POST [assuming you are posting the process name] else a GET with appropriate Query parameters required for successful process execution.

Even better way is POST for Starting the process, GET to see the status of the Process like complete, in-progress etc.